# AWS Security group access to particular resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new AWS and trying to figure out AWS security model.  I have created 2 VMs and 2 Groups(https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/groups). I want to assign System1 to Group1 and System2 to Group2.

From AWS console, I assigned System1 to Group1 using Change Security Group option. When users belongs to Group1 log into AWS they should see only System1.

I tried with IAM Management and Resource Group options, didn't work as expected. Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resources in AWS are "listable" by all Users in your account. However only the users in Group 1 can perform actions on the resources outlined in your Group 1's policy, same with Group 2.

May I suggest using https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/ instead. It'll allow you to have seperate accounts for "Group 1", where only Group 1's resources will show, then you can control access those resources further with IAM.

- Group 1 == Team 1, with a Group 1, with a Policy that can EC2FullAccess, and Group 2 with a Policy that can S3FullAccess.
- Group 2 == Team 2, with the same config.

The resources in Team 1, won't display in Team 2.

*or*

You can keep it mega simple, and just let everyone see everything, but you just control actions to those resources with IAM groups/policies.

You could also, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html where you create a group for all people that can X, then a role that can actually perform the X action, and assume the role to that group - that way you don't have to define polices per users/groups.